# Find items not in common between lists in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-2.6

I have two very large lists (say 50,000 strings) in Python 2.6, *a* and *b*.

Here are two options.  Which is faster, and why?  Is there a better way?

```
c = [i for i in a if i not in b]
```

Or...

```
c = list(a)  # I need to preserve a for future use, so this makes a copy
for x in b:
    c.remove(x)
```

Comment: You can make a copy of a list using slice notation: `c = a[:]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use sets:

```
c = list(set(a).difference(b))
```

or, if order is important:

```
set_b = set(b)
c = [i for i in a if i not in set_b]
```

Comment: `list(set(a).difference(b))` will only return the elements present in `a` and not `b`, but not those present in `b` and not in `a`.

Comment: @Bonifacio2: note that the OP's attempt did just that; create an asymmetric difference.

Comment: Yeah. I think the question title is not aligned with what was asked.

Comment: Nice solution! I tried simple benchmarking by measuring start time and end time using time.time() and this set technique is super fast compared to the others, followed by the second method in question. The first method is extremely slow (30 seconds versus under 1 second for the other 2. No idea why.

Comment: @haraprasadj: use the `timeit` module to compare Python snippets like these. :-)